# Parsing JSON object to javascript with ajax/php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using JavaScript/AJAX so that when a user selects a 'deal_name' from the dropdown menu, other information will be displayed using the showPartnerInfo function.  Here's the relevant snippet from the k1.php file:

```
function showPartnerInfo(str){

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("pshipInfo").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var dealName = str;
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'get_partnerInfo.php?q=',
                //dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {"q" : dealName},
                success: function(json){
                    //alert(data);
                    var data = JSON.parse(json);
                    document.getElementById("pshipInfo").innerHTML = data.tax;
                    //document.getElementById("pshipInfo").innerHTML = json[1];
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("error");
                }
        });
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ("session.php");
include ("navbar.php");
$taxID = "";
?>
<form style="margin-top: 60px" action="k1_2DB.php" method="post">
<div class="well">  
<h1>K1 - Tax Update</h1>
<?php        
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT deal_name FROM tbl_deal";
    $result = mysqli_query($DBconnect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<select name='deal_name' onchange='showPartnerInfo(this.value);'>
              <option value=''>Select Investment</option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";   
        }
    }else{
       echo "<select name=''><option value=''>No Investments Found</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Here's the get_partnerInfo.php file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
include("config.php");
$q = $_GET['q'];

if (!$DBconnect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($DBconnect));
}

$pship_query = "SELECT tbl_deal.deal_name, tbl_partnership.pship_name, 
                    tbl_partnership.pship_taxID,            
                    tbl_partner.partner_name, 
                    tbl_deal.deal_tax_id 
                FROM tbl_deal 
                    INNER JOIN tbl_partnership 
                        ON tbl_deal.pship_ID = tbl_partnership.pship_ID 
                    INNER JOIN tbl_partner 
                        ON tbl_deal.partner_manag_ID = tbl_partner.partner_ID
                WHERE tbl_deal.deal_name = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($DBconnect,$pship_query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$myArray = array(
    "tax" => $row["pship_taxID"],
    "name" => $row["pship_name"], 
    "dealTax" => $row["deal_tax_id"],
    "parName" => $row["partner_name"]);
$json = json_encode($myArray);
echo $json;
mysqli_close($DBconnect);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the above code, 
nothing happens, and I get the following error in the console:

> VM245:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at Object.success (k1.php:60)
>           at u (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at k (jquery.min.js:2)
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

I've seen the other answers about dealing with this, (both stack overflow and others), and nothing seems to help.  It's important to note that under the network tab in the developer tools, the output of get_PartnerInfo.php is:

```
  {"tax":"45666XA","name":"Daniels and Partners","dealTax":"SEA485","parName":"Harry Petre"}
```

and if I don't use JSON.parse in the showPartnerInfo function, the above is displayed without a problem.  It seems that there's a problem from converting the json object to javascript.  Any advice?

Comment: That can't be (all) the output for get_PartnerInfo.php -- you're outputting a doctype, HTML-tag, head and body. None of those should be there for a JSON response.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Because *facepalm* ‍♂️ and factually incorrect information in the question…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rickdenhaan's comment, I took out the html and body tags from get_partnerInfo.php and just left the text inside the .  Now it works with no problem!